# jQuery Mobile textarea resizing issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a textarea element which sits in the footer of the page (to emulate the native compose box for messages in iOS). As text is entered, it grows or shrinks accordingly. The height of this element seems to be computed to 52px.

I would like the height to be smaller. However, setting the initial height (without important) simply gets overwritten by 52px. Setting the initial height to around 35px (with important) disables the auto-grow feature and a scroll bar appears instead. I've played around with the web inspector, but I can't seem to figure out where this 52px is being computed from.

What is the solution to this problem? The code is pretty straight forward. I am working with jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.0.

`HTML`

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" class="custom-footer">
        <div class="group-footer">
            <div class="map-icon">
                <img src="assets/compose-action-arrow@2x.png" style="width: 25px;height: 25px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="text-box">
                <textarea name="textarea" class="define-textarea" id="inbox-continue-conversation"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="send-link"><a href="#" id="inbox-continue-answer-button">Send</a>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

`CSS`

```
.define-textarea {
font-size: 1em !important;
border-color: #cccccc !important;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[image: Height is 52px. Ideally, I would like it to be around 35px.]
  [image: The auto-grow feature should look like this.]

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to replicate this behaviour on jsfiddle @marionebl

Comment: Could you post it anyway? The differences often help and the rest of your code could provide hints, too.

Comment: Not sure if this helps at all, but here goes http://jsfiddle.net/48c7x/

Comment: Ok, jquery-mobile does some crazy stuff on `textarea` elements, inspecting it further. Docs: http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/

Comment: I know. I'm this close to pulling all my hair out for something that looks deceivingly simple. Thanks for the help though @marionebl!

Comment: do you want to grow? fix its' height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue stems from [this line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/749c78e6407da683a720d15635bc938b3b864df2/js/widgets/forms/autogrow.js#L119) in the jQuery mobile source. When calculating the new height for an autoresizing jquery mobile `textarea` form widget, it adds 15px to the calculated height.

This is hard coded, so no option to tweak here.

You could work around this with a monkey patch for the textinput widget. It would have to do two things:

1. Add a default option for the added height, e.g. `autogrowSpace`
2. Override the private function `_updateHeight` in `$.mobile.widgets.textinput` in to use this new option

**Working jsfiddle employing the discussed monkey patch**:

http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/48c7x/2/

**Example** `_updateHeight` copied from [jQuery mobile source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/749c78e6407da683a720d15635bc938b3b864df2/js/widgets/forms/autogrow.js):

```
(function ($, undefined) {

    $.widget("mobile.textinput", $.mobile.textinput, {
        options: {
            autogrow:true,
            autogrowSpace: 0,
            keyupTimeoutBuffer: 100
        },

        _updateHeight: function () {
            var paddingTop, paddingBottom, paddingHeight, scrollHeight, clientHeight,
            borderTop, borderBottom, borderHeight, height,
            scrollTop = this.window.scrollTop();
            this.keyupTimeout = 0;

            // IE8 textareas have the onpage property - others do not
            if (!("onpage" in this.element[0])) {
                this.element.css({
                    "height": 0,
                        "min-height": 0,
                        "max-height": 0
                });
            }

            scrollHeight = this.element[0].scrollHeight;
            clientHeight = this.element[0].clientHeight;
            borderTop = parseFloat(this.element.css("border-top-width"));
            borderBottom = parseFloat(this.element.css("border-bottom-width"));
            borderHeight = borderTop + borderBottom;
            height = scrollHeight + borderHeight + this.options.autogrowSpace;

            if (clientHeight === 0) {
                paddingTop = parseFloat(this.element.css("padding-top"));
                paddingBottom = parseFloat(this.element.css("padding-bottom"));
                paddingHeight = paddingTop + paddingBottom;

                height += paddingHeight;
            }

            this.element.css({
                "height": height,
                    "min-height": "",
                    "max-height": ""
            });

            this.window.scrollTop(scrollTop);
        },

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Great find! I would have never thought to look there, the 15px they've hard coded in seems a little weird though. Any idea why they would? But otherwise, thank you very much for a well explained solution!

Comment: I guess the added height is there to ensure a visible distinction between `textarea` and `input`. Why this UX decision is imposed on everyone without an easy way to override it - I guess simply nobody thought about use cases similar to yours. But then jQuery mobile is OS and one could publish a pull request via GitHub for this. Perhaps I come around to do this later today, will update my answer then.

Comment: +1 Great answer in my view, because you have provided a solution to override default behavior!